# Safari not correctly displaying percentage based grid system

Tags: javascript, css, grid

I have a grid system which has an issue whereby the columns don't always fill the row div. This is a Safari only issue and affects both desktop and mobile browsers. It appears to be due to Safari not being able to fully support sub pixel rendering.

A solution suggested below asks that i switch off border-box. However i really need this to stop the grid breaking. Are there any solutions to fix this. I don't mind if the solution is JS based along as it doesn't affect performance too much. Thanks.

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 75rem;
}
.row:before, .row:after, .row .row:before, .row .row:after, .row .row.edge:before, .row .row.edge:after {
    content:" ";
    display: table;
}
.row:after, .row .row:after, .row .row.edge:after {
    clear: both;
}
.row.edge > .col {
    padding: 0;
}
.row.edge .row {
    margin: 0;
}
.row .row, .row .row.edge {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 -.75rem;
    max-width: none;
}
.row .row.edge, .row .row.edge.edge {
    margin: 0;
}
.col {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 .75rem;
    float: left;
}
.s-5 {
    width: 5%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/matt3224/XT9QZ/1/

Image of issue here! [Columns not filling row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjx18.png)

Comment: I am not getting the same issue that you show in the image below. What browser are you using?

Comment: Its a safari issue, sorry i should have mentioned that

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you put `padding: 0 .75rem;` in your `.col`, try removing that code and it will be as you want. It's because it you define a fix padding value, by doing so you accidentally give min. width for your cols.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but even if i remove the padding i still get this spacing at the end when i resize. I have updated my fiddle plus take a look at the issue here http://postimg.org/image/wnfeha4lp/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `box-sizing: border-box;`

remove this CSS

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XT9QZ/2/).

or else you can overwrite `box-sizing`.

CSS

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 75rem;
    box-sizing: content-box; /*Add this css*/
    }

.col {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: content-box; /*Add this css*/
}
```

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XT9QZ/4/)

Comment: Ah ha! Brilliant it appears its to do with the way safari/apple round percentages to the nearest pixel. As there doesn't appear to be support for sub pixel layouts, however i have just booted up Yosemite to check and this problem has been fixed in safari 8 and iOS 8 so hopefully this will just be a temporary measure or at least a graceful fallback.

Comment: I know removing css for * may create a problem, you can try the 2nd solution.

Comment: Its a shame because i really do kinda need box-sizing with it being a nest able grid and all

Comment: Did you tried the second solutions to give box-sizing content-box to .row and .col

Comment: Yes but this then breaks my grid. I'm kind of relying on box-sizing to make the grid work nicely